# How to fix: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed?

Tags: android

I have a problem with android database and cursors. Time to time (very rarely) happens, that I get crash report from customers. It's hard to find out why it crashes, so it's really some minor bug.

Here is exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.throwIfClosedLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:962)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:599)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:348)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:894)
```

Then I have methods like this one (that it crashed in the line c.moveToNext() with that error). It almost never crashes but sometimes it does and i can't reproduce it.

```
public List<AlarmModel> getAlarms() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String select = "SELECT * FROM " + Alarm.TABLE_NAME +" WHERE "+ Alarm.COLUMN_NAME_ALARM_FLAVOR_ID+" = -1 ";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(select, null);

    List<AlarmModel> alarmList = new ArrayList<AlarmModel>();

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        alarmList.add(populateModel(c));
    }

    if (!alarmList.isEmpty()) {
        if (db != null) {
            db.close();
        }
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
        return alarmList;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: First you should check if the cursor is in first position by using `c.moveToFist()` in `if` statement and inside the `if` body you add you `while` loop code.

Comment: thanks ! i'm trying on your suggestion

Comment: so why using c.moveToFist() in if statement before while loop code ?

Comment: this is to check if the cursor has value and should start with first position of the data retrieved from db..

Comment: so can use (c != null) instead of c.movetoFist() ?

Comment: use both for safety...I would recommend that..I always do this.. `if (c != null && c.moveToFirst())`

Comment: ok ! i'll do but is there any way to reproduce this issue because it's rarely happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple things might cause this issue:
a. You are calling db.close() before accessing the data.
b. Or db.close() is being called by some other method and you are still trying to access data from database from other method with same database reference.

Comment: so Is it necessary to remove db.close() ?

Comment: so why this issue is rarely happen ? i couldn't reproduce.

Comment: yes, i can't reproduce the issue. but a lot of my user encounter this problem based on Crashlytics log. Any idea how to reproduce ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove db.close()

This may be a multi thread issue, the db is closed by another thread. You can check all places of db.close().

I usually open database in Application.onStart(), and only close it in Application.onDestroy(). Thus no worry about multi-thread database open/close.

Comment: it mean that removing db.close() could solve the problem ? I think it probable impact to other places

Comment: I have about 10 APPs in play store, all have only db.close() in Application.onDestroy. I never had a single problem on database.

Comment: @Le Minh that means database is a real "Singleton" and should not impact any places.